# How can I handle error 404 in async/await fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

Is there any opurtinity to catch Error where there will be no data provided?
I recevie Error 404 but can't for example console.log it...

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;

    const api_call = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);

    const data = await api_call.json();

    console.log(data);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Image error from Browser]

Comment: `if (api_call.ok) { 200-299 }` `api_call.status` contains the status code

Comment: In your screenshot the response is in the output, what do you mean by "I recevie Error 404 but can't for example console.log it" ?

Comment: Tip: use https!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `try catch`:

```
getWeather = async (e) => {
    try {
        e.preventDefault();
        const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
        const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
        const api_call = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
        const data = await api_call.json();
        console.log(data);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('error: ', e);  
    }
}
```

Comment: I would kinda like to see how `await` influences the need for the `try catch` block ;)

Comment: This one gives back same eror i had before

Answer (score 6):

Regardless of using `async/await` or promise chaining, the `fetch` API returns a `promise` containing a `Response` object.  The response object contains a `status` property which returns an HTTP status code.  Before you call the `.json()` method on your `response` object you can check to see `if res.status === 200`.  For example, the OpenWeather API will return a HTTP status code of `200` for successful requests.  So, to check if your API request was successful, you could do the following ...

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;

    const api_call = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);

    if (api_call.status !== 200) {
        // You can do your error handling here
    } else {
        // Call the .json() method on your response to get your JSON data
        const data = await api_call.json();
    }
  }
```

You can see more of the `Response` object properties and methods [By viewing the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

Answer (score 3):

Just examine the `status` property of the resolved promise before you try to extract the body with the `.json()` method.

```js
async function test() {
  const api_call = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://example.com/fake/fake`);
  console.log(api_call.status);
}

test();
```

Comment: just a tip https://httpbin.org is a good site for cors and testing has stuff like https://httpbin.org/status/{xxx}

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
class App extends React.Component{
  getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const country = e.target.elements.country.value;
    try {
        const api_call = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);

        const data = await api_call.json();
        console.log(data);
    } catch(e) {
       console.log(e);
    }

  }
```

Comment: Resolve of this is Error Failed to compile
./src/App.js
  Line 22:  'data' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.